# selenium.open() becomes unresponsive in an iterative test

Tags: selenium-rc

I have a set of test steps that I have to execute with different parameters. I have scripted this in Eclipse/TestNG, driven by the parameters supplied via an excel sheet. 
Now, the test steps involve setting the property of a page, and then opening another page to confirm that the property is set. So, in effect, I use a simple `selenium.open("my_first_url");` at the beginning of the test, set the property, and then another `selenium.open("my_second_url");` to open the other url where the assertion is performed.
There are about 9-10 sets of test data.

Here's the problem-
By the time the test iterates through the 4th iteration, selenium RC simply pauses (hangs?) at the `selenium.open(...);` command. 
I have noticed this happening before, but simply thought of it as a test anomaly.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This tends to happen in Firefox, and not IE :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure of what causes this in FF. To work around, I upgraded to the alpha release of the selenium server 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Add below line above `selenium.open()` method

```
selenium.setTimeout("0");
```