# Why doesn't Selenium return from this internal HTTPS URL?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, testng, selenium-grid

Can someone please tell me why Selenium can't return from opening this internal HTTPS URL?

https://red1cert.red-usa.com:37443/index.php3

After a call to `selenium.open("https://red1cert.red-usa.com:37443/index.php3")`, Selenium hangs and after a very long while, it terminates with server error. Help please.

Comment: Are you sure that URL is reachable? I can't open it from here.

Comment: So sorry. Just realized that i sent a url that is within our network. hmm!! Any idea what could be the problem based on the behavior described above Tim?? Thanks

Comment: Can you access this URL from a browser manually on the same machine that Selenium is running on? Does Selenium successfully launch a browser, and if so what happens in the browser? It may be a security certificate issue, but you should at least see the browser attempt to open the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet an expert with Selenium RC, trying it currently. That said, I discovered that if you set speed to something like 1000, it might help!

In Java: selenium.setSpeed("1000");
In PHP: $this->setSpeed("1000");

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This may attribute to the `selenium.open()` bug, with 1.0.3, where it becomes unresponsive. I encountered this for a script opening multiple sites sequentially.
Assuming your URL is reachable, outside of Selenium, try using Selenium 2.0 and executing the same command.

Here is the link to my question from before - 
[selenium.open() becomes unresponsive in an iterative test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787402/selenium-open-becomes-unresponsive-in-an-iterative-test)