# selenium rc killing firefox at random points for no reason

Tags: firefox, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm running test using behat, but this basically runs phpunits selenium driver, to do integration tests

everything was working fine but for no apparent reason firefox quits at some point in the middle of my test suite the selenium rc log looks like this

```
09:23:53.157 INFO - Command request: setTimeout[30000, ] on session 62b513ea550a419898a79f912beecc69
09:23:53.180 INFO - Got result: OK on session 62b513ea550a419898a79f912beecc69
09:23:53.263 INFO - Command request: open[/request/step1, ] on session 62b513ea550a419898a79f912beecc69
09:23:53.318 INFO - Got result: XHR ERROR: URL = http://local-test.account/request/step1 Response_Code = -1 Error_Message = Request Error on session 62b513ea550a419898a79f912beecc69
09:23:53.321 INFO - Command request: testComplete[, ] on session 62b513ea550a419898a79f912beecc69
09:23:53.321 INFO - Killing Firefox...
09:23:53.356 INFO - Got result: OK on session 62b513ea550a419898a79f912beecc69
09:23:53.371 INFO - Command request: open[/request/step1, ] on session null
09:23:53.374 ERROR - Exception running 'open 'command on session null
```

at what point in the test it quits doesn't seem to follow any pattern.

i've tried rolling my projects code back to before I was having problems but to no avail

Comment: What version of Selenium are you running?

Comment: Selenium rc, I've mitigated to problem by reducing the frequency of the loops to check for location after a redirect, something selenium 2 does oob. But I can't find a php driver for selenium 2 and don't have time to write one.

Comment: If you're using a version of Selenium RC prior to 1.0.3 then you may need to upgrade due to an XHR check when using the `open` command. You can use the latest 2.x version as it also includes the latest RC (with various fixes since the last 1.x release).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Selenium 1.3, try upgrading to Selenium 2.0. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787402/selenium-open-becomes-unresponsive-in-an-iterative-test) is how I resolved my problem with `selenium.open();`

Comment: I'ld love to switch to selenium 2 but can't find a php driver for it

Answer (score 0):

This is possible when you are not passing correct website address. What are you passing, what is the URL of your website.